# Is there a Gnome Shell shortcut to minimize a window?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, gnome-shell

`F11` makes a window go full screen. Is there a shortcut that minimizes a window? I am using Arch Linux with Gnome Shell.

Comment: It depends on your distribution. In Ubuntu there is preset keyboard short-cut, which I can't remember, because I changed it to `Alt-F9`, which is what it used to be, and which ties in with the other window controls. (I think it was something like `Ctl-Sh-0`.)

Comment: What distribution and what window manager?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Gnome Shell actually supports this. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is the default key. If you want to change the key go to:

```
Settings -> Keyboard -> Windows -> Hide Window
```

---

Since this answer has gained some traction it is good to also know that:

1. This works on MacOS as well.
2. This does not work on Windows, however, you can achieve the same effect by using a tool like AutoHotkey.

Comment: This one works like a charm in Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome)

Comment: No problems in Fedora 28 either. Never thought to search for "Hide" rather than minimize though.

Comment: works on Debian 9

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: too bad the rest of the workd talks about minimize a window..... 
I had to look very hard to find this..... Thanks!!
maybe because its a oneway without a toggle?

Comment: Works in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: For the record, the same key also works on macOS.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  And I do think a PR needs to be made upstream for searching shortcuts for the word "Minimize" as I did that and nothing come up and I had to do a search for "gnome minimize window shortcut" to find this answer that says if I had searched for "Hide" then it would have come up. It should come up for both "Hide" and "Minimize".

Comment: Is there a way to make the window stop losing focus though? I want to minimize with superdown and the maximise again with superup. But the window loses all focus when minimised to the taskbar when using "hide window". It's not as useful like this

Answer (score 9):

I know the OP didn't ask for it but for the sake of completeness, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> minimizes all windows (think of it as "show **D**esktop"). Ubuntu 19.04, Gnome 3.32.1.

Comment: This also works on Windows 10. Amazing, I wasn't aware of this shortcut. Thank you.

Comment: `Super` + `D` also restores all windows if hit again.

Comment: Interestingly, this does not seem to work for me on RHEL 8.3 (Gnome 3.28.3). Super + H does "hide" the window, however.

Comment: Does not work in GNOME on Debian 11. Bleh.

Comment: Gnome 44.1 doesn't detect the Super + D shortcut, in 'custom shortcuts' the combination doesn't return any conflicts with existing native hotkeys. Fedora 38.

Answer (score 5):

Using `gsettings`:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize  
['<Super>h']
```

Set <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings minimize "['<Super><Shift>h']"
```

Comment: thank you!! I'm on popOS and "minimize" isn't in the Keyboard Shortcuts menu at all for some reason; this worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

On the GNOME desktop environment, you can use CTRL-ALT-D to minimise all and give focus to the desktop. You can also use ALT-F9 to minimise the current window. I think these are the same for Ubuntu/Unity.

Comment: I'm on Gnome 3.24.3  on Fedora 26, CTRL-ALT-D does nothing.

Comment: ALT-F9 was exactly what I wanted (minimize current window) (on Ubuntu 16.04 with MATE). Thanks!

Comment: none of these work on openSUSE Tumbleweed on a Visual Studio Code window...

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't set as a default for my environment, but setting it in Gnome 43.3 went as follows:

1. Open **Settings**. `<Super> type Settings <Enter>`
2. Navigate to **Keyboard**. `Left pane`
3. Select **View and Customize Shortcuts**. `Bottom`
4. Use *Search* to find **Hide all normal windows** under Navigation.
5. Set shortcut as desired. For example, I used Super + D.

[Here's what my settings look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A38Mh.png)

Answer (score 1):

works in gnome
super+down(↓)
For minimizing the window size of an application
super+up(↑)
for maximizing the window size of an application
super+right(→)
for throughing application window to right side of monitor screen
super+left(←)
same as above

Answer (score 0):

2023 in Debian 12 + Gnome 43 + Wayland

Not sure what people mean by super key. It is:

"Command" key + "H" key

Comment: Debian 12 + Gnome 43 + Wayland

Comment: Do you perhaps have an Apple branded keyboard?

Comment: yes indeed, but I don't think there is a super key on windows keyboard either so it is not universal.

Comment: I think that be "super" they mean the OS' key, which is Command on Mac keyboards and the "Windows" key on Windows keyboards.

Comment: gotcha thanks! Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button) it is pretty much a configurable key that is not used consistently depending on user environment